# What is the input parameter type in an AWS Lambda function handler written in Java when using function URL to trigger the Lambda function?

Tags: java, function, url, input, aws-lambda

I want to write a simple Lambda function handler in Java which would act as a simple API (based on the input event object it's going to decide what http method was called (GET/POST/...) and prepare a proper response).
I would like to utilize the "function URL" option which I can set in the Lambda function configuration to make it possible to call the function handler's endpoint directly (from a browser or Postman).
The problem is I don't know what type of data my Java function handler should receive in such case.

The following piece of code works fine if the input parameter was an APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent object (which I would receive if the request was sent through API gateway or if I provide an "API gateway API Proxy" event template JSON which comes in various AWS examples).

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent> {

    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(final APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent input, final Context context) {

        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
        logger.log("aws lambda function invoked");

        logger.log("input: " + input.getBody());
        logger.log("log: httpMethod = " + input.getHttpMethod());       // RETURNS null !!!!
        logger.log("log: path = " + input.getPath());                   // RETURNS null !!!!
        logger.log("log: queryStringParameters = " + input.getQueryStringParameters());
        
        ...
```

The problem is that if I deploy such a function handler (with an APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent object as the input parameter) and then try to trigger this function handler by sending a simple request from Postman to the lambda function's URL, the request data get transformed into an APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent object after all but it's not populated correctly - the httpMethod or path are both null even though they were correctly set in Postman.
I therefore assume I need to change the input APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent parameter to be of another type, I just don't know which type it should be and I haven't been able to find an answer so far.

I would think it must be quite easy to get a simple request from Postman/curl/browser/... and receive it in the Java function handler with all the request details (including http method or path) so I just must be missing something (most likely the correct input type of the event object)...

I'll be grateful for any piece of advice.